# Overriding a Django admin.ModelAdmin function for all models

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm sort of stitching together contrib.databrowse (to view) and contrib.admin (to edit), and I'd like to override the *response_change* function in admin.ModelAdmin so that when you click save, it redirects back to the object in databrowse rather than the admin. I know how to do this for a specific model in admin.py, like:

```
class WhateverAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def response_change(self, request, obj):
        # stuff

admin.site.register(Whatever, WhateverAdmin)
```

but I'd like to apply that to all of my models without just copying the function over and over (i.e. override it in admin.ModelAdmin itself). Where and how should I do that?

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could have your admin classes inherit off of the WhateverAdmin class.

So for example, your app is laid out as...

```
\site_defaults
    __init__.py
    admin.py
\your_app_1
    __init__.py
     models.py
     admin.py
\your_app_2
    __init__.py
     models.py
     admin.py
```

For the 2 apps you have, in the admin.py the code would be like...

```
from site_defaults.admin import WhateverAdmin

class YourApp1Admin(WhateverAdmin):  # << note it's not admin.ModelAdmin
    # code over here
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution thanks to [T. Stone's Idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210035/overriding-a-django-admin-modeladmin-function-for-all-models/1210044#1210044).

I didn't think to register each model with the same Admin class if I wasn't changing anything else. The ones that need special changes inherit the new class, the rest call admin.site.register with it:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def response_change(self, request, obj):
        # code 

class SomethingAdmin(MyModelAdmin): 
    # code specific to the Something model 

admin.site.register(Something, SomethingAdmin)
admin.site.register(Another, MyModelAdmin) 
admin.site.register(OneMore, MyModelAdmin)
```